# biomaRt getBM not working due to getNodeSet {XML} error

Tags: r, xml, biomart

I'm running the following code in r and it is not working. getBM seems to not work for any arguments. Am I doing something wrong?

```
ibrary(biomaRt)

ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "genes")
ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "ensembl", 
                       dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", 
                       mirror = "useast")
affyids <- c("202763_at","209310_s_at","207500_at")
getBM(attributes = c('affy_hg_u133_plus_2', 'entrezgene_id'),
       filters = 'affy_hg_u133_plus_2',
       values = affyids, 
       mart = ensembl)
```

The error I'm getting is
`Error in getNodeSet(html, path = "//div[@class='plain-box float-right archive-box']")[[1]] :  subscript out of bounds`
I tried this both in r version 3.6.3 and 4.1

Comment: I think it is because the biomart service of ensembl is currently unavailable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensembl is temporarily unavailable according to https://www.ensembl.org/info/.